# date string giving M/dd/yyyy when taking from excel to string variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, date-format, excel-import

I am reading data from excel to mvc controller using linq.

after reading the data I am doing some validation. In excel there is a column `DOB`

the date in `DOB` column at excel is stored in `dd/MM/yyyy` format

but when I am trying to take the length of that column I am getting only 9.

eg: let the date is `28/09/1983`

```
int len = member["DOB"].toString().Length;
```

where `member["DOB"]` is a column from excel sheet in which `DOB` is date formatted as `dd/MM/yyyy`

Here the value of `len` will be 9. When I done a message the value I am getting from `member["DOB"].toString()`  is `9/28/1983`

I am not able to understand what is the real issue. This is happening only when website is calling from server. In local it is working fine.

> Note:- Local and server date time format is dd/MM/yyyy

Linq used to read excel sheet

```
 var member = from memRec in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName)
                                      select memRec;
```

Comment: might be the default date-time format on server is different.

Comment: how to check that?? short time in regional setting is dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: member["DOB"] is what type?

Comment: @JamesBlond member["DOB"]  is reading it from excel sheet. In excel that column format is dd/MM/yyyy date format

Comment: I got that, but what I mean is member["DOB"] a DateTime type or some weird excel library type or already a string?

Comment: @JamesBlond `var member = from memRec in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select memRec;`  this is how i take that

Comment: That is not what James is asking. He's asking what the type of that cell in the Excel file is.

Comment: _"I am not able to understand what is the real issue"_ - that you're calling `ToString()`. If you want to work with dates, convert it to a date.

Comment: @CodeCaster my question is the cell contain 28/09/2015 and when i assing to a string variable how it is becoming 9/28/2015

Comment: No, the cell does not contain "28/09/2015", that is not at all how Excel stores dates. You are converting it to string. You don't seem to understand that dates as a storage unit and .NET variable are something entirely different than a date displayed on your screen. You are the one converting it to a string, so you will have to figure out how one can format a date in the format they want.

Comment: @CodeCaster in excel we can format the cell to date "dd/MM/yyyy" format. I can see the excel and value in that cell is "28/09/2015".. Also it is successfully uploading in my local system

Comment: Again, that is **how Excel is displaying that date**. It does not change how the date is stored in the file, nor how you read it from code.

Comment: why not pass ("dd/MM/yy") in the ToString?